# D3 doesn't load a CSV file from an external URL

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to load a CSV file using D3.csv(MY_EXTERNAL_URL) function,but it doesn't load. Seems that it doesn't find the file itself.

Here is my code.

```
d3.csv ("http://localhost:8080/SOME_LINK", function (tuples) {
console.log(tuples);
//tuples is empty
});
```

However, when I copy/paste MY_EXTERNAL_URL on browser it downloads the CSV file instantly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm thinking maybe I miss some headers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By 'external' you mean from another domain / web site?

I guess you are running into the Same Origin policy of browsers. You cannot issue an ajax request to another domain, this is forbidden by your browser.

Read more about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm doing. I'm trying to get the file from localhost:8080 server, but my .html which from I'm sending an ajax request is in different server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the d3.csv function? Because your code says you're using the d3.json function.
If that doesn't work, you may need to add the ".csv" ending to your file and then open it up as SOME_LINK.csv

Comment: Yes. Sorry for misspelling.